# Automatic include files in folder in Visual Studio 2019 project

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I have folders that fills by third part application, and I need to store all the files as part of my project. Include it one by one even manually a whole folder is pretty annoying, because I forced to make it everytime when new file apears or removes.

How to make it with Visual Studio Community?

Comment: Just don't include them one by one.  Use Shift+Click in the dialog to select all of them.  If a new file gets added then you do have to select just that one file.  Unless you delete the existing files from the project first, that can also be done quickly by using Shift+Click.

Comment: @HansPassant I didn't mean it at all. There is no problem to include set of files, problem is I forced to watch if some new files appeared, I want it to includes automatically without manual actions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had similar issue working with webpack. I had to manually includes files in visual studio generated by webpack. You have to edit.csproj file.

Right click the project, and click on

> Unload project

Right click the unloaded project and click on

> Edit YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.csproj

Edit under , example, I wanted to include all files under my /Scripts/dist/ to be included whenever I was going to publish them. ** includes all files or folders.
You can also see other options here on [VisualStudio documentation site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-items?view=vs-2019#content).

```
<ItemGroup>
   .... other items
   <Content Include="Scripts\dist\**" />
   .....other items
</ItemGroup>
```

You can also do it as,

```
<Content Include="css\*.min.css" />
<Content Include="js\*.min.js" />
```

If the files are dynamically created from outside (like webpack), then you can also set it to be invisible or hidden (greyed-out) by:

```
 <Content Visible = "false" Include="Scripts\dist\**" />
```

Note: Even though you see files are greyed out (as if it was not included), the files will be included when you publish. In my case, it was included when I refreshed my project.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer :) It definitely what I wanted